# Is QML the way to go if designing a game in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Was looking into making a game with Qt and was wondering if QML has gotten to the point yet where it could be used as a serious tool on the desktop.  Have seen some post from Qt stating that they will be transitioning most things to QML eventually, so this seems like it may be the way to go, at least according to Qt.

Edit: I realize that QML probably wouldn't be the best bet for a 3D game with heavy graphics.  Was looking more for something that did mostly 2D stuff like a platformer type game.

Seen this http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/08/12/a-guide-to-writing-games-with-qml/.  So its obviously possible to some extent.  I have also seen some impressive games made solely with java script, which I believe is the base of QML.  I was just curious as to what would be the best way to go with Qt at the moment since things have been changing lately...

Comment: What sort of game is it?  If you're developing a 3d game, I'd suspect it's not the right tool.  If you're doing a 2d "app" like game (that's the best I can describe it.  I'm talking about the common type of games you see on smart phones/ ipads, which mostly feature moving sprites laid over each other, and which tend to be puzzle games) Then QML is probably what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may depend on "how long" you want to wait before releasing your game.

The Trolls/Qt are re-doing its "graphics stack" right now:  Rather than historic "every-widget-renders-itself" (which is the wrong paradigm for games and rich mobile apps), they are re-implementing to a single graphics stack that renders the WHOLE interface, where the "widgets" themselves are mere data-sets that feed into the rendering.  In short, the goal is to make desktop/mobile applications with the exact same performance as the high-end games have done for decades (with their own graphics stack that looks nothing like the typical `X/Xlib/Motif/Xvt/Win/MFC/Qt` applications graphics stack).  Further, the Qt5 plans (in planning/development now, they claim a release sometime next year) are reliant upon OpenGL for this graphics stack implementation.

After this work, the pipeline will be:  `Widgets==>QML==>(C++ Graphics Stack)==>Hardware`.  Currently (Qt 4 and previous) it is:  `QML==>Widgets==>(C++ Graphics Stack)==>Hardware`.

You can google for various posts/discussions on this, or here's a long-ish presentation that talks about these efforts: http://qt.nokia.com/developer/learning/online/talks/developerdays2010/tech-talks/performance-do-graphics-the-right-way/

IMHO, QML makes more sense for games, since the interface components are "independent actors" (e.g., not tied to each other through layouts).  That's also why QML makes so much more sense for mobile (where real estate is a premium), and for very flashy desktop apps (although it is still relatively young and unproven for that).

QML already has lots of rendering/animation options, but they are mostly a very rich 2D (but with which you could simulate 3D pretty well).  The QML 3D is undergoing heavy revision right now, but the new stuff looks really good (and sits on OpenGL).  So, if you want heavy 3D, it might be experimentation time for the moment, until you see the new Qt5 interfaces and can take advantage of the hardware acceleration (depending on how much 3D you need).

The performance specs I've seen from the new Qt5 stuff with the new graphics stack (in prototype development) are quite impressive, so much so that I've been thinking about writing some games in QML just to play with it.  If this were twelve-months-from-now (or so, after the release of Qt5), I'd bet QML would be the best/easiest decision for games (because the components are independent actors, it's so simple to use, and I'd push all the game-specific heavy stuff into C++, which is really easy to do with QML on top).

Comment: Very interesting answer! I was aware that Qt was making some big changes for Qt 5 and the QML stuff, but wasn't quite aware to what extent.  So long term it doesn't look like a bad way to go.  The biggest concern I would have is that since this so new at the moment, things are bound to change quite a bit by the time Qt 5 rolls around.  Although performance of existing QML stuff may actually improve it seems.  Kind of an awkward (and interesting) time to be getting into this I suppose...

Answer (score 7):

QML is definitely a viable option for designing 2D games and can save you a lot of time and lines of code.
[V-Play](http://v-play.net/) (v-play.net) is a cross platform 2D game engine based on Qt/QML  with many useful V-Play QML game components for handling multiple display resolutions & aspect ratios, animations, particles, physics, multi-touch, gestures, path finding and more ([API reference](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-group.html)).

If you are curious about the games made with V-Play, here is a quick selection of them:

- [Squaby](http://games.v-play.net/squaby/): a tower defense game
- [Chicken Outbreak](http://games.v-play.net/chickenoutbreak/): a platformer like Doodle Jump
- [Blockoban](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.impossibru.blockoban): puzzle game
- [Crazy Elephant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xom.xxmassdeveloper.CrazyElephant): a game similar to Angry Birds
- [Snowball Mania](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxmassdeveloper.SnowballMania): multiplayer action game
- [Blitzkopf](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.fhooe.mc.blitzkopf): brain game

Answer (score 4):

Remember that QML is only designed to lay out the UI. Fundamentally, it acts as a QGraphicsView with lots of utility functions (code in QML is at least three times shorter than the Qt/C++ equivalent, at least, that's how I felt it)

The core of the application is still handled by either javascript files (if things are not too complex) or C++/Qt files (if you want the full extent of Qt possibilities)

As Jeremy Salwen said, for a game that looks like a smartphone app game (big sprites that move with nice transitions, with simple logic behind it), then QML is more than sufficient.

But if you want something complex, then you will end up using in QML only QDeclarativeItem classes that you will have previously defined in C++. Not that useful.